# Include a php variable in a <div id>

Tags: php, html, web

I want to appear the name of the user who is log in.

```
<div id="userbar">Hello Name. Not you? Log out.</div>
```

I tried this but doesn't works.

```
<div id="userbar">Hello <?php $_SESSION('log')  ?>. Not you? Log out.</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You forgot an `echo`

```
<div id="userbar">Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['log'];  ?>. Not you? Log out.</div>
```

And for sure you have to call `session_start()` at top

Comment: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/chr1sm1/public_html/new/testheader.php

Comment: @user3045939: yes for sure, I have copied your code, I corrected `$_SESSION('log')` to `$_SESSION['log']`

Comment: Alternate to this - `<div id="userbar">Hello <?=$_SESSION['log']?>. Not you? Log out.</div>`

Answer (score 1):

and also you can check if user is logged in because  if $_SESSION['log'] doesnt have a value it will show error

```
<div id="userbar">Hello <?php echo isset($_SESSION['log'])? $_SESSION['log'] :"" ?>. Not you? Log out.</div>
```

Comment: sorry littlle mistake typo

Answer (score 0):

Php having different method to print

- single quoted
- double quoted
- heredoc syntax
- nowdoc syntax (since PHP 5.3.0)

Example

```
echo 'this is a simple string';//(single quoted)
echo 'this is a simple string';//double
<?php
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;heredoc
<?php
$str = <<<'EOD'
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using nowdoc syntax.
EOD;//newdoc
```

[More Details](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

In your case you may use any one of following:

```
echo $_SESSION['log'];
print($_SESSION['log']);
```

Remove **(**. $_SESSION is array you can use its index like `$_SESSION['indexname']` [DETAIL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)